# Why I can't truncate text

Tags: html, css

I want to truncate text after word end, not to truncate on half word, like in the following example.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lz36hs10/1/)

What I want to do I is ilustrated in the image below:

[image]

Code:

```css
div {
  font-size: 20px;
  width: 80%;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
}
```

```html
<div>

  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut incididunt labore lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit
  sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore lorem ipsum
  dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit sed do eiusmod
  tempor incididunt ut labore.

</div>
```

Comment: Try adding `white-space: nowrap;`.

Comment: Not working, because, text is't in 2 lines.

Comment: can be fixed by giving a fixed width (no pun intended)

Comment: good question i am waiting for positive answer as well.

Answer (score 3):

I think this will work.

```
div{
font-size:20px;
width:80%;
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
-webkit-box-orient: vertical;
display: -webkit-box;
-webkit-line-clamp: 2;
 -ms-word-break: break-all;
 word-break: break-all;
 word-break: break-word;
}
```

You can also check here : [https://justmarkup.com/log/2015/07/dealing-with-long-words-in-css/](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-wrap)

Comment: @ml92 uptated. Try one more time.

Comment: not work, I want to truncate after full last word displayed

Comment: Oh yes I have updated. It works well for me now @ml92

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know the CSS property `text-overflow: ellipsis` has a limitation in that fact that it only works on a single line of text.

So for your question, I don't believe it is possible in simple CSS to achieve what you're wanting (or at least I can't figure it out)

I've come up with a way to truncate a word on multiple lines. See this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lz36hs10/9/) or the snippet below:

```css
div {
  width: 80%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 1em;
  max-height: 3em;
  text-align: justify;
  padding-right: 1em;
  font-size: 20px;
}
div:before {
  content: '...';
  position: absolute;
  right: 2px;
  bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div>

  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit sed do eiusmod lorem tempor incididunt eiusmod tempor ut labore incididunt lorem ipsum et consectetur verylongwordrighthere elit sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt labore lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
  consectetur adipiscing elitsed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
  ut labore lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing
  elit sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore.

</div>
```

It uses the `:before` pseudo element to "create" an ellipses in the right bottom corner.

Although it may not be the easy solution your looking for, I do not believe it is possible in a simpler way to achieve what you want in CSS (someone correct me if I'm wrong)

*Note*:
There is a way to do it with jQuery and some regex

```js
p = $('p');
div = $('div').height();
while (p.outerHeight() > div) {
  p.text(function(j, e) {
    return e.replace(/\W*\s(\S)*$/, '...');
  });
}
```

```css
div {
  font-size: 20px;
  width: 80%;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin nisi purus et ut dictum ligula, dapibus testinglongword, mattis et dui. Nunc porttitor accumsan orci id luctus. Phasellus ipsum metus, tincidunt non rhoncus id, dictum a lectus. Nam sed ipsum a lacus sodales
    eleifend. Vestibulum lorem felis, rhoncus elementum vestibulum eget, dictum ut velit. Nullam venenatis, elit in suscipit purus posuere mauris, quis adipiscing ipsumel velit testinglongword rhoncus elementum vestibulum eget, dictum ut velit.
    Nullam venenatis, elit in suscipit purus posuere mauris, quis adipiscing ipsum urna ac quam.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `word-wrap: break-word;`

```css
div{
  height:50px;
  font-size:20px;
  width:80%;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  position: absolute;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
   word-wrap: break-word;
 margin-right: -0em;
  padding-right: 0em;
}
div:before {
  content: '...';
  position: absolute;
  right: 1px;
  bottom: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div>

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore.

</div>
```